# Android - MediaPlayer streaming displaying a Progress Dialog before playing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my application, I will playing music from URL. So it would still take some time to 
play the audio since it is through streaming.
I wanted to implement a ProgressDialog while waiting for the `MediaPlayer` to play/start.

Here is my method for playing the audio:
        public void playMedia(String songIndex) {

```
            ProgressDialog pDialog;
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading. . . ");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

            Uri songUri = Uri.parse(songIndex);
                    try {
                        mp.setDataSource(context, songUri);
                        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mp.prepare();

                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally{
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    if(mp!=null)
                        mp.start();
        }
```

This is how I tried to implement it. 
But it did not work.
And i have Exceptions like this:

```
        08-27 19:48:13.896: E/InputEventReceiver(8798): Exception dispatching input event.
        08-27 19:48:13.896: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:599)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:326)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:285)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at com.app.adapters.MyRowAdapter.playMedia(MyRowAdapter.java:126)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at com.app.adapters.MyRowAdapter$2$4.onTouch(MyRowAdapter.java:522)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7185)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2280)
        08-27 19:48:13.906: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8798):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2023)
```

Are there other ways to implement this? Like where should i put this one?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The context object you have used here,  `pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);` will not work if you have referred to getApplicationContext().

Instead try replacing it with, Activity Context like this,

```
 pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ActivityName.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Use Async Task:

     private class MediaPlayer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                     Uri songUri = Uri.parse(songIndex);
                        try {
                            mp.setDataSource(context, songUri);
                            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                            mp.prepare();

                        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
return mp;
            }        

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {             
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                pDialog.setMessage("Uploading file. . . ");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: ooops..my bad..
it's not actually uploading. the message is suppose to be just loading

Comment: It will just show dialog box until your doesn't get downloaded or you can set some time  at which dialog box will be seen

Comment: yah yah. but my concern is when using this is when stopping the mediaplayer.
this is happening in separate thread right

Comment: Both media player and dialog box will not be played together.1st dialog box will complete its task then media player will start its work.1st try it

Comment: im quite confuse. you are returning MediaPlayer but put String in the AsyncTask Return...